# Springboot throwing TypeMismatchException exception while accessing a boolean value from application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, boolean

I have springboot project where i am using a boolean variable from application.yml into my service file. Spring boot throwing exception At the time of startup.

Below code is for using the variable in my service file :

```
@Value("${security.validation}")
private boolean securityValidation;
```

Below is in application.yml :-

```
security:
  validation: false
```

Below is the error thrown :-

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${security.validation}]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1092)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 109 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${security.validation}]
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor.setAsText(CustomBooleanEditor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:468)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:441)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:61)
    ... 113 common frames omitted
```

I have tried false and 0 both but for both it's throwing same exception.

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
 @Value("#{'${security.validation}'}")
    private boolean securityValidation;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Ghrissology , it's throwing same exception with "#{'${security.validation}'}" as well.